# Using quad (scipy.integrate) and decimals

Tags: python, scipy, decimal

I need to integrate a function with a lot of precision, for instance:

```
from decimal import * 
from scipy.integrate import quad
getcontext().prec = 30
a = Decimal('1.1') + Decimal('1.2') 
print type(a)

def f(X):
    return quad(lambda x: X, 0, 1)[0]

b = f(a)
print "{0:.30f}".format(b), type(b)
```

And I get

```
<class 'decimal.Decimal'>
2.300000000000000266453525910038 <type 'float'>
```

I would like to use quad as my integration tool, but unfortunately it seems as though it converts the output to a float. I want the output of the integration to be of higher precision. How do I achieve this?

Comment: With `scipy.integrate.quad`, you can't.  `quad` is a wrapper of QUADPACK, a Fortran code written using double precision floating point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look at using the [mpmath](http://mpmath.org/) library. It supports high precision integration (http://mpmath.org/doc/0.19/calculus/integration.html).